# How to remove attribute(manufacturer) name Url in magento 1.9?

Tags: magento-1.9, url, url-rewrite

How to change url www.example.com/brands/nike to www.example.com/nike used manufacture attributes in magento 1.9

Comment: Maybe you use category "brands" in url or "brands" it is attribute?

Comment: Yes, Used as attributes

Answer (score 1):

Please go to admin panel.

**System -> Configuration -> Catalog -> Catalog -> Search Engine Optimisations**

Please set value **No** in tab Use Categories Path for Product URLs

Answer (score 0):

This free module will remove the parent category and will fix the issue 
https://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/category-url-seo-free.html
[image]